# Mesibo On Premise Deployment - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, curl, mesibo

I am trying to configure mesibo communication services On-Premise Deployment and tried to deploy while backend application using docker - FastCGI - NGINX. I have followed the below URL https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#hosting-mesibo-backend-apis Please see the title "Hosting mesibo backend APIs". I have used the 11443 port to deploy the application in the docker.

While checking the command `sudo netstat -ltnp` getting the following output. So the process is running correctly.

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      267497/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11443           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      535097/backend

When I try to run the command

curl http://0.0.0.0:11443 => getting error as "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Please help me to get out of this issue.

========= Found the Issue - But it may be help someone

run the command 'ifconfig' to find the docker ip address. then try the curl command with that ip address.

Comment: You should use the actual IP address of docker and not 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes , i have run the command 'ifconfig' and got the docker ip address. Thanks @mesibo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, mesibo DOES NOT have any web server so you can't use curl directly.

Refer to this document

https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#hosting-mesibo-backend-apis

It clearly says you should configure and point to your web server. In turn, your web server will connect to the mesibo FastCGI server. From the above doc

> you need to configure a URL on your webserver to access backend APIs.
> Any API request received on this URL should be forwarded to the mesibo
> backend FastCGI server at the port specified in the command, port 5000
> in above example.

Please follow the document and configure a URL on your web server and then curl to that URL.